# How to get a picture to be under another picture on mobile, while being effected by inline-flex on desktop?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[the picture of the website on mobile, and the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNLvB.png)

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
    <div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.thedrisco.co.il/octopus/Upload/images/Pages/restor-his%201.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="display: inline-flex; padding-top: 45px;">
      <img src="https://www.thedrisco.co.il/octopus/Upload/images/Pages/classic2%201%20(6).jpg" style="height: 240px;" /></div>
    <div style="padding-right: 67px;">
      <img src="https://www.thedrisco.co.il/octopus/Upload/images/Pages/classic2%201%20(5).jpg" style="height: 240px;" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

> I have this piece of code.. now, I need the images that are in inline flex to fit in a column instead of next to eachother on mobile, and the  images to stretch to the size of the device of course. Any Ideas? I added an  image for reference to what I'm talking about. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

When working with Bootstrap, it’s easiest to define each row separately, and then divide up each row into different columns based on the device, so you could have your restorer image on its own row and the two classic images in the same row.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-end mb-3">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
        <img class="float-right w-100"
          src="restor-his%201.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-7 mb-3 mb-md-0">
        <img class="float-right w-100" src="classic2%201%20(6).jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-md-first">
        <img class="float-right w-100" src="classic2%201%20(5).jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

To get the ratio right between the two classic images, I did reduce the width from 430 to 419px, rather than setting the height to a fixed value.